# Retrieiving individual cell data of a DataTable row in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need to make a the last column of the row disabled or enabled based the value present in the previous column of the same row. We have used Datatables to create the table.

I am not able to get the values present in the cells of the row while rendering the data using `mRender` for comparing. Can anyone please help in getting the values of the row in `mRender`?

I tried with `iDataRow` and also with `createdRow` and `fnRowCallback` to make the last column disabled after the creation of table.

I don't know why `createdRow` is not working in `aoColumns`.

Please find my code snippet below :

```
"aoColumns": [{
    "mData": "productID",
    "bSearchable": true,
    "bSortable": true
}, {
    "mData": "barcode",
    "bSearchable": true,
    "bSortable": true
}, {
    "mData": "fulfillmentChannel",
    "bSearchable": true,
    "bSortable": true
}, {
    "mData": "dateAvailable",
    "bSearchable": true,
    "bSortable": true
}, {
    "mData": "stockStatus",
    "bSearchable": true,
    "bSortable": true
}, {
    "mData": "stockAllocation",
    "mRender": function (data, type, full, iDataRow) {
        console.log(iDataRow); 
        <c:if test="${User.permission eq 'All'}">
            return '<input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:100%" id="stockAllocation" validationDescription="<spring:message code="validation.mustBeDigit"></spring:message>" validationRules="^[0-9]+$" name="stockAllocation" value="' + data + '"></input>'; 
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${User.permission eq 'ReadOnly'}">
            return data;
        </c:if >
    },
    "bSearchable": true,
    "bSortable": true
}],
```

I want the values of `fullfillmentchannell` and `stockAllocation` into `mRender` write a condition and make the `stockAllocaton` field disabled.

Answer (score 1):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use `full` variable to access row's data, for example `full['fulfillmentChannel']` or `full['stockAllocation']`.

Then you could write in `mRender` function:

```js
"mRender": function (data, type, full, iDataRow) {
   if(full['fulfillmentChannel'] === 'A' && full['stockAllocation'] === 'B'){
      data = 'Disabled';
   } else {
      data = 'Not disabled';
   }

   return data;
}
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sszky09y/) for demonstration of similar example using DataTables 1.10.